# Using std::iter_swap for std::optional

Tags: c++, c++11, std, c++14, option-type

Looking at [`std::iter_swap` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) I concluding, that:

```
struct A {};
std::experimental::optional< A > x{A{}}, y{A{}};
std::iter_swap(x, y);
```

is legal. Is this the case?

The requirement for arguments to be *ForwardIterator* means, that they should just satisfy a requirement: after dereferencing an (iterator) passed object should remains in valid (dereferenceable?) state. Is it right understainding?

Comment: Concept forward iterator is: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator

Comment: _ForwardIterator_ has many more requirements in addition to the one you mentioned.

Comment: @ForEveR I read that. What the requirement to referenced type and iterator itself can be violated? I think the reference for `std::iter_swap` can be outdated in light of presence of such new containers as `std::optional`.

Comment: `optional`s are possibly empty. `iter_swap` implementations will break on such empty `optional`s.  `swap(optional, optional)` deals with empty, and full, optionals.  I don't see the point?

Comment: @Yakk Above code clearly present non-empty optionals. Invalid and past-the-end iterators are not dereferenceable too. Anyways see answer and discussion below.

Comment: @Orient and once you have a non-empty optional on a line of code (known statically at compile time), then you (usually) shouldn't be using an optional on that line of code.  If you do use it, `swap(*optional, *optional)` will be more correct than `iter_swap`...  Basically, I'm trying to find the *practical* use case here, and I don't see it (above and beyond it being undefined behavior).

Comment: @Yakk really question should be about `std::shared_ptr`. It has no practical use at my mind in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ForwardIterator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) is more constrained, than you say.
Your example will work only if something like this implementation will be used:

```
template<class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2>
void iter_swap(ForwardIt1 a, ForwardIt2 b)
{
   using std::swap;
   swap(*a, *b);
}
```

but since it's not guaranteeed you actually shouln't use `iter_swap` for optional. You really should just use [swap for optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/swap2)

Comment: OK, implementation of `iter_swap` may pass arguments (iterators) by value, but not reference. It is important here.

Comment: @Orient The signature of `iter_swap` clearly says that it takes arguments by value. There is no room for the implementation to do anything else here.

Comment: Don't want to ask another question, but what about `std::shared_ptr`? Smart pointer is still iterator?

Comment: They should be dereferenced into the `std::iter_swap` and can be. Which *ForwardIterator* invariants may be violated in this case?

Comment: @Orient what is for example type `std::iterator_traits<std::shared_ptr<T> >::reference`?

Comment: I don't know (you know). But is there any references here at all? Are they can be involved into implementetion?

Comment: @Orient there can be just concept check, or something else, implementation may check, that `ForwardIt` meets requirement of `ForwardIterator`.